# Is there a way to safely do try/catch in DBT?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jinja2, dbt

I am trying to connect to different projects in google cloud platform using a run_query statement, and then using an if execute to know if there was any issues connecting to the project. However, the execution is interrupted saying that the project does not exist, and it never reaches the if execute.

If there was a way to know if a project exists without having this type of error it would also work

```
{% set connection_query %}
SELECT
    *
FROM
    {project}.`region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
{% endset %}

{% set result = run_query(connection_query) %}

{% if not execute %}
      -- do something
{% endif %}
```

Right now I have the following code, but since some projects do not exist, the execution is interrupted saying:
Access Denied: Table xxxxxxx:region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS: User does not have permission to query table xxxxxxx:region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS, or perhaps it does not exist in location EU.

Is there a way to make this work?